# Gmail APIの認証情報でエラーがでる

Tags: gmail, webapi

Gmail APIを使ってメールの自動送信をしたいのですが、API取得の時点でうまくいきません。
以下の記事を参考にさせていただき、設定を行いました。

[Python を使い、Gmail API 経由で Gmail の送受信を行う - Qiita](https://qiita.com/muuuuuwa/items/822c6cffedb9b3c27e21)

「OAuthクライアントIDを作成」をクリックの際に画像のようなエラーが発生します。
解決方法がなかなか見つからず困っています。回答よろしくお願いいたします。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
The request failed because one of the field of the resource is invalid.
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]